# Image files are not stored in

Tags: php, regex, foreach

Address is loaded with an array of images.

```
Array ( [0] => http://postfiles6.naver.ne/20140318_37/nurisdent_1395133546151D77vg_JPEG/%BB%F3%BE%CF%B5%BF%C4%A1%B0%FA_%B4%A9%B8%AE%B2%DE%BC%AD%BF%EF%C4%A1%B0%FA_%283%29.JPG?type=w2 
        [1] => http://postfiles5.naver.net/20140318_228/nurisdent_1395133546620ybrcN_JPEG/%BB%F3%BE%CF%B5%BF%C4%A1%B0%FA_%B4%A9%B8%AE%B2%DE%BC%AD%BF%EF%C4%A1%B0%FA_%281%29.JPG?type=w2 
        [2] => http://static.se2.naver.com/static/full/20130612/emoticon/1_05.gif 
        [3] => http://postfiles1.naver.net/20140318_224/nurisdent_1395133546848KfeYv_JPEG/%BB%F3%BE%CF%B5%BF%C4%A1%B0%FA_%B4%A9%B8%AE%B2%DE%BC%AD%BF%EF%C4%A1%B0%FA_%282%29.JPG?type=w2 
        [4] => http://static.se2.naver.com/static/full/20130612/emoticon/1_10.gif 
     )
```

I'm trying to save as follows :

```
http://postfiles6.naver.ne/20140318_37/nurisdent_1395133546151D77vg_JPEG/%BB%F3%BE%CF%B5%BF%C4%A1%B0%FA_%B4%A9%B8%AE%B2%DE%BC%AD%BF%EF%C4%A1%B0%FA_%283%29.JPG?type=w2
-> 1.jpg
http://postfiles5.naver.net/20140318_228/nurisdent_1395133546620ybrcN_JPEG/%BB%F3%BE%CF%B5%BF%C4%A1%B0%FA_%B4%A9%B8%AE%B2%DE%BC%AD%BF%EF%C4%A1%B0%FA_%281%29.JPG?type=w2
-> 2.jpg
```

I only accept an array of regular expressions, so that the file name has been processed

```
$data = preg_replace_callback("/.+\/(.+)(\?.+)?$/", create_function('$matches', '$tmp = pathinfo($matches[1]); return $tmp["filename"];'), $i);
```

I just leave the file name, and then tried to save a file via file_put_contents.

```
foreach($my_img as $i){
    $tUrl = $i;


    $data = preg_replace_callback("/.+\/(.+)(\?.+)?$/", create_function('$matches', '$tmp = pathinfo($matches[1]); return $tmp["filename"];'), $i);

    $rUrl = "http://blogimgs.naver.com"; //Referer 
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $tUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $rUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30) ');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    $get = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    foreach($data as $v)
    {
        file_put_contents('./blog_img/'.$v.'.jpg', $get);
    }
}
```

0 byte file is created, but this will be.

I wonder what happened to this because.

Comment: did you bother checking `var_dump($get)` for boolean false, which'd indicate that curl failed somehow? Have you tried hitting your urls manually?

Comment: How old is your PHP version? Anonymous functions were added in 5.3, you don't need to use `create_function` any more.

Comment: Instead of the regular expression, why not use `parse_url`?

Comment: It looks like `$data` is a string, not an array, how can you use it with `foreach`?

Comment: You have a bunch of incomplete sentences in the question. _but this will be_ and _happened to this because_.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're doing. In the question, you say you want filenames `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, etc. But in the code, you're using `preg_replace_callback` to get something from the URL to put into the filename. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

Change your regular expression to:

```
/.+\/(.+?)(\?.+)?$/
```

You need to use a non-greedy repetition operator, because the next group (the query string) is optional. With a greedy quantifier, `.+` will continue to the end because it can allow nothing to match the optional group.

But it would probably be better to replace the use of the regular expression with `parse_url`:

```
$parsed = parse_url($i[1]);
$info = pathinfo($parsed['path']);
$data = $info['filename'];
```

Comment: The following error occurs.                                        parse_url() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in            Then parse_url ($ i) by replacing the string in the array it's better?

Comment: Where is that array coming from? I thought you had an array of strings, and you're looping over them with `foreach($my_img as $i)`.

Comment: Isn't `$my_img` the array at the top of the question?

Comment: $ my_img is the address of the web page but the img tag has been parsed value.

Comment: preg_match_all('@<img\s[^>]*src\s*=\s*(["\'])?([^\s>]+?)\1@i',$contents,$my_img);
$ My_img set of regular expressions, and it is so.

Comment: `preg_match_all` returns a 2-dimensional array, you need to use `$i[1]` to get the URL. I've updated the answer. You also need to do this in `$tURL = $i[1]`.

Comment: However, if you do this, save the file only can I not? I'm trying to say is that you are trying to save the image in the array will be.

Comment: I can't understand what you're saying, your English is very poor.

Comment: I tried to run as your advice. i [1] is an array with only one value, the address of the image file will be created only one.

Comment: That's why it's in a `foreach` loop. That loop will process each image URL.

Comment: In fact, I process each image URL in the foreach loop that had been wondering how. 

But one of the images, each image being created to find ways to keep in place

Comment: You're not writing understandable English. I'm usually good at deciphering gibberish, but not this time. I give up, please stop asking me for help with this.